# SDL: No available video device - prepackaged apps on Devuan

Tags: opengl, debian, driver, sdl

I'm trying to compile an SDL2 "Hello here's a window" application but it's not working. This is the error I get:

```
Could not initialize SDL: No available video device
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

int greatSuccess = 1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) == 0) {

    // this code path is not hit, omitted 

  } else {
    printf("Could not initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    greatSuccess = 0;
  }
  return !greatSuccess ;
}
```

The error that causes this generalizes to pre-packaged applications; `mgba-sdl`, a frontend to `mgba` based on SDL2, produces the same error:

```
Could not initialize video: No available video device
```

I say the same, because the `No available video device` is (presumably) produced by `SDL_GetError()` in both cases.

Enumerating video devices from inside the application results in:

```
0: dummy
```

My platform is Devuan ASCII, which is based on Debian 9/Stretch.

Here's the output from `ldd ./hellowindow`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0
```

`glxgears` does work. `glxinfo` produces:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel GM45 Express Chipset 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Some things I've tried:

- `export DISPLAY=:0` (didn't work, and it already was set, to `:0.0`)
- `SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11` (didn't work, and it fails before this starts to make sense, see the enumeration of video drivers)
- compiling with `sdl2-config --static-libs` instead of `--cflags --libs`

Perhaps SDL2 does not support OpenGL 2.1? What's going on here?

This is all rather odd to me, like a video driver issue except I have drivers that work, confirmed by `glxgears` and `glxinfo`.

Comment: Where does your SDL2 installation comes from? `/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0` is the only `local` library in your list - it it custom built? If so, your SDL2 is built without any video implementation.

Comment: It's from the Devuan pre-built package repo, I've not built it myself.

Comment: @keltar Thank you, that's it! Turns out I have two installations, I forgot I built it from source a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

keltar spotted the issue in one go: I had a second, locally built install of SDL2.

I fixed the issue by removing the following files and directory:

```
/usr/local/bin/sdl2-config
/usr/local/include/SDL2/
/usr/local/lib/libsdl*
```

The copies in `/usr/local` where built without graphics support and took precedence over the package manager's version, which is why it didn't work.